# Site not scrolling on mobile devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, skrollr

Site's built on bootstrap, I'm using `skrollr.js`to add a parallax effect to the header images. I think it's this that's not allowing the site to scroll. I've tested on multiple devices and on even more in Chrome's emulation.

I've read around that `overflow: hidden` can cause problems, and it appears that `skrollr` is adding those styles to the `html` tag.

Link - http://goo.gl/YofGx7

Comment: What did you mean by not scrolling, put the code that you have in the issue so we can see it

Comment: You can inspect the element in responsive viewer in firefox, and copy-paste the code here.

Comment: Sorry, yes, as in not vertically scrolling when swiping on the device. I'm not sure of the exact code that's causing the problem, could try inspecting the page in browser?

Comment: And you can set the inline css style to the html markup

Comment: Not sure I follow your last comment @AlKush , could you explain?

Comment: Couldn't achieve what I needed with `Skrollr`, have switched to `stellar.js`

Answer (score 0):

You said that overflow: hidden can cause problems, so why don't you kill that style by adding the inline css style in your html markup. For example, if the tag who has the style of 'overflow hidden' has the id of #body, then in the html markup you set the style: like

```
   <div id="body" style="overflow:scrolll;">
   ....
   ....
   ....
   ....
   ....
   </div>
```

The direct/inline style of "overflow:scroll;" in the tag will remove the style of overflow:hidden; in an external css file.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, `skrollr.js` was overwriting the inline style too. As I mentioned above, I moved away from `skrollr.js`, `stellar.js` is much more straight forward for the simple task of parallax backgrounds (no object re-positioning, etc.) in my opinion! Thanks for the help anyhow

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nandha, however I no longer am using skrollr on the project, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939746/site-not-scrolling-on-mobile-devices/45674711#comment40688527_25939746)