# Website not scrolling in mobile devices with skrollr

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, skrollr

I am using twitter bootstrap for my website . I am also using skrollr.js for parallax effect in background.But website becomes fixed to top while viewing in the mobile devices.but According to the skrollr [documentation](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) i am also using `#skrollr-body` in my document But it does not scroll in mobile devices.I have seen some questions from stackoverflow and seen the answers and tried as follows :

```
#skrollr-body{
  position : relative;
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
```

How can i fix the scrolling problem?

Comment: Seems to be the same issue [I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939746/site-not-scrolling-on-mobile-devices/45674711), not the answer you're looking for but I recommend using another library 